# The rearrangement of an absolutely convergent operator series

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am reading Zorich II Chapter 10 A more general approach to Differential calculus

In section 3 The differential of a mapping ,Example 6 and Proposition 2, He made a comment which says " the absolute convergence (in terms of norm convergence) of the series under study ensures that one can freely perform arithmetic operations on the series (exchange the terms of the series!)."

So the question comes to,

The rearrangements of an absolutely convergent operator series ,in maybe Banach space,  converge to the same operator.

I can only know rearrangements do converge, but how to prove converge to the same one?

I find this statement not obvious and the the proof of real series sum does not work here because it seperates the real terms $a_n$ into positive and negative groups($a_n^+$and $a_n^-$) which cannot apply to operator series.

Comment: The proof for numerical series can be copied with replacement of $|\cdot|$ by $\|\cdot\|.$ There is no need to study positive and negative parts.